# resizing Telegram inline keyboard

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

[Telegram's inline keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/2-0-intro#new-inline-keyboards) is a great feature with lots of different use cases.

Inline buttons are added as a list of items like this:

```
inline_keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton(text="button", callback_data="button"),
                  InlineKeyboardButton(text="reset",callback_data="reset")]]

inline_keyboard_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard)
update.message.reply_text("hi", reply_markup=inline_keyboard_markup)
```

The above code adds two buttons each with the half width of the chat screen.

I know that for the the normal keyboard button there is a `resize_keyboard` parameter which somehow can be used.

My question is that is there a way to resize the **inline buttons**? for example to make it full width or quarter width.

Comment: really useful feature!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do it for now. :(

You can suggest this to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport), they might add this feature to next version.

Answer (score 17):

You can adjust the width of the buttons by changing the quantity of them in one line.[image]

```
$inline_keyboard = array('inline_keyboard' =>
        array(
            array(
                array(
                    'text' => "\xF0\x9F\x93\x9D Заказы", 'callback_data' => '/orders'
                ),
                array(
                    'text' => "\xF0\x9F\x93\x8A Статистика", 'callback_data' => '/stats'
                ),
                array(
                    'text' => "\xF0\x9F\x92\xB0 Баланс", 'callback_data' => '/balance'
                )
            ),
            array(
                array(
                    'text' => "\xF0\x9F\x92\xB0 Баланс", 'callback_data' => '/balance'
                ),
                array(
                    'text' => "\xF0\x9F\x93\x8B Счета", 'callback_data' => '/bills'
                )
            ),
            array(
                array(
                    'text' => "\xF0\x9F\x93\x9D Заказы", 'callback_data' => '/orders'
                )
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Comment: I've ended up positioning each button in a separate row